# How to use create-react-app bundle in plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I want to build my react project into a bundle.js file and then use that bundle in a plain javascript file. This is to integrate the react application with another application that uses plain javascript

Do I need to eject my application and change the webpack config so that the index.js gets exported?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import data from './mocks/data'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store'
function callback() {
    return data;
}
function loadApp(root, callback) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App getData={callback} /></Provider>, document.getElementById(root));
    serviceWorker.unregister();
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {
    loadApp('root', callback)
}
export default loadApp
```

Comment: Why eject? build it and use the bundle file where you want

Comment: Just use `yarn build`, then look at the generated index file and static folder. Combining that with your existing app shouldn't be a problem. As long as you have the root element and you're linking to the bundled js and css, the React app should run. What have you tried to far? How did it fail?

Comment: I have tried using this application using serve , but the application doesnt load. I need a way to call the load App function from the html file.
https://pastebin.com/H3xJJ8F2

Comment: @ChrisG I tried to attach the function to the window object but I get an error